# Clamp rigidbody2D Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, clamp

I have a class that deals with the control of a ship, and I want to clamp the position on the y axis.

```
 public class ControlledRigidbody2D : MonoBehaviour
{
public float verticalInputAcceleration = 1;
public float horizontalInputAcceleration = 20;
public float maxSpeed = 10;
public float velocityDrag = 1;
private Vector3 velocity;
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 acceleration = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * verticalInputAcceleration * transform.up;
    velocity.y += acceleration.y * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 accelerationRight = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * horizontalInputAcceleration * transform.right;
    velocity.x += accelerationRight.x * Time.deltaTime; ;
    velocity = velocity * (1 - Time.deltaTime * velocityDrag);
    velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
    transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever dealing with `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` there are two main rules

1. Do not do things in `Update` but rather in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) which is used for all Physics and Physics2D engine related calculation.

   Moving the object in `Update` would cause some jitter and braking the Physics reactions like collisions etc.
2. Do not go directly through the `Transform` component but use properties and methods of the `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` instead!

   Like in your case [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) or [`Rigidbody2D.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)

   Again moving the object via the `Transform` component breaks the Physics

so your code should be like

```
// already reference the component via the Inspector
[SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;

Vector3 acceleration;
Vector3 accelerationRight;

privtae void Awake()
{
    if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Get user input within Update
private void Update()
{
    acceleration = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * verticalInputAcceleration * transform.up;
    accelerationRight = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * horizontalInputAcceleration * transform.right;
}

// update the Rigidbody in FixedUpdate
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    velocity = rb.velocity;

    // do these here so Time.deltaTime uses the correct value
    velocity += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
    velocity += accelerationRight * Time.deltaTime;
    velocity = velocity * (1 - Time.deltaTime * velocityDrag);
    velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);

    // Problem: MovePosition expects a value in global world space
    // so if your velocity is in local space 
    // - which seems to be the case  - you will have to convert 
    // it into a global position first
    var newPosition = rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(velocity  * Time.deltaTime);
    rb.MovePosition(newPosition);
}
```

or alternatively you could also simply directly assign this new velocity to the rigidbody

```
// update the Rigidbody in FixedUpdate
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    velocity = rb.velocity;

    // do these here so Time.deltaTime uses the correct value
    velocity += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
    velocity += accelerationRight * Time.deltaTime;
    velocity = velocity * (1 - Time.deltaTime * velocityDrag);
    velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);

    rb.velocity = velocity;
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: yes, I understood, just that your code has some lag. In the sense that it shakes.

Comment: shake slowly but still shake....and that is neither ok nor optimized.